# Changing v-data-table sort-icon props does not work

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Changing sort-icon props does not change icon but works on codepen. The sort icon is still **mdi-arrow-up**, I want to change it to **mdi-unfold-more-horizontal**

```
    <v-data-table @click:row="show" :headers="headers" :items="myItems"
            class="elevation-1" 
            sort-icon="mdi-unfold-more-horizontal"
            :hide-default-footer="true">
    </v-data-table>
```

Please check my codepen, here.
[link](https://codepen.io/SRN48/pen/zYWzoJr)

Editor: vscode,

[v-data-table-header API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table-header/#props)

Vue: 2.7.2

Comment: In your codepen example, it works for me..

Answer (score 0):

I can change the sorting icon by adding :headerProps="headerprops" to v-data-table, like adding a header slot to customize the table header.

headerprops is an object.

```
      export default {
      data() {
          headerprops:{
              "sort-icon": "mdi-unfold-more-horizontal"
          },
        }
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
<v-data-table
  :items="items"
  :header-props="{ 'sort-icon': 'mdi-triangle-down' }"
></v-data-table>
```